# Access Violation in Cordova app when double clicking on a list item

Tags: angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, access-violation, mshtml

We are creating a Cordova app using AngularJS. On Windows Phone 8.1 the app crashes when double clicking on a list item. When debugging 'scripts only' the app just disappears leaving an Access Violation message in the output window. When setting debugging to native, I get an Access Violation exception in MSHTML.DLL with the following stack trace:

```
MSHTML.DLL!CDMTouchTarget::SetTag(struct IUnknown *,unsigned int) Unknown
MSHTML.DLL!CIndependentHitTestManager::HitTestPointer(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,long) Unknown
MSHTML.DLL!CIndependentHitTestManager::IndependentHitTestWndProc() Unknown
MSHTML.DLL!CIndependentHitTestManager::s_IndependentHitTestWndProc() Unknown
MINUSER.DLL!Core::Yield::WndProc(struct Core::FunctionPointer,struct Core::WindowHandle,struct Core::WindowMessage,struct Core::WParam,struct Core::LParam) Unknown
MINUSER.DLL!Core::Window::DeliverMessage() Unknown
MINUSER.DLL!Core::ThreadInfo::ReceiveSentMessage(void) Unknown
MINUSER.DLL!Core::ThreadInfo::ReadMessageEntryWorker() Unknown
MINUSER.DLL!Core::ThreadInfo::ReadMessageEntry(class Core::MessageFilter *) Unknown
MINUSER.DLL!Core::Api::gggGetMessageW(struct Core::MsgStruct *,struct Core::WindowHandle,struct Core::WindowMessage,struct Core::WindowMessage) Unknown
MINUSER.DLL!minGetMessageW() Unknown
MSHTML.DLL!CIndependentHitTestManager::IndependentHitTestThreadProc() Unknown
MSHTML.DLL!CIndependentHitTestManager::s_IndependentHitTestThreadProc(void *) Unknown
NTDLL.DLL!RtlUserThreadStart() Unknown
```

I have no idea what to research further. Did anyone experience this before